# Getting Element from a given innerHTML character

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="root"><span id="first">a</span><span id="second">b</span></div>
```

Starting from the "a" character, I'd like to get its parent span element:

```
var a = document.getElementById('root').innerHTML[17]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How exactly do you get/know about the "a" character? If you have a text node, just do `node.parentNode`. Or you could traverse all text nodes to find one containing "a". Please provide more information about the context.

Comment: Are you *really* getting the `a` from its position in the grandparent element's `innerHTML`? If you are, that sounds like the most fragile approach you could ever have found (and in any project that features updates (*at all*) is unworkable in the long-term. And what is it you're trying to *do* with the element once you've found it? If it's styling, I'd suggest `div :first-child::first-letter { font-weight: bold; }` (or whatever), with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Giving your HTML, following code

```
document.getElementById('root').children[0].firstChild
```

will give you your "a" text node, so

```
document.getElementById('root').children[0].firstChild.parentElement
```

will give your the parent SPAN, but this seems a bit redundant unless I am missing something.

If (what's more likely) you have multiple SPANs with different content inside of that DIV and you want to locate specific SPAN based on the content - you can use something like this:

```
var aSpans = document.querySelectorAll('#root span');

for (var i=0, ln = aSpans.length; i < ln; i++) {
    if (aSpans[i].innerHTML == 'a') {
        console.log(aSpans[i]);
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://oscarotero.com/jquery/):

```
var spanContent = "a",
    spanElement = $("#root > span:contains('" + spanContent + "')");

spanElement.css("color", "red");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/G9E6y/)